# Trouble compiling FUSE filesystems on OS X

Tags: macos, makefile, fuse, pkg-config

OS: OS X Mavericks (v10.9)

FUSE: [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) v2.6.2

I'm trying to compile the [loopback filesystem in C](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/tree/master/filesystems-c/loopback), but I'm getting this error:

```
$ make
cc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse -Wall -g  -F/Library/Frameworks -o loopback loopback.c -losxfuse
ld: library not found for -losxfuse
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [loopback] Error 1
```

Trying to compile [boxfs2](https://github.com/drotiro/boxfs2) also produces this error:

```
$ make
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libapp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libapp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libapp' found
Package libjson was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libjson.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libjson' found
Compiling boxfs.c
cc   -c boxfs.c -o boxfs.o
boxfs.c:15:10: fatal error: 'fuse.h' file not found
#include <fuse.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [boxfs.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

As far as the first problem, you need the OSXFUSE library somewhere the compiler can see it, or you need to tell the compiler where it is.

You may have some success using `mdfind` to locate the `osxfuse` library file, then add `-L/path/to/osxfuse` to the compile/configure script to the makefile.

Similarly, the for the second, try making sure boxfs2 knows about the fuse header: Looks like adding `-I/usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse` might do it.

Comment: Oh: If I had to guess, `-L/usr/local/lib/osxfuse/` might be your answer, but that'd be a guess.

Comment: Close. `-L/usr/local/lib/` fixed it. Still trying to figure out boxfs2 though.